# Are Magento's cron jobs a suitable tool for running things just once?

Tags: magento-1, cron

I want to notify customers in 24 hours after they've done some specific thing in my store. I have an idea how to do that with Magento's cron jobs. But are cron jobs a suitable tool for this? Cron is usually used to run tasks repeatedly rather than once. Is there a better suited tool in Magento? For example, I would use `at` instead of `cron` to run a task once at specific time on my Linux machine.

Comment: It depends. Do this job has to be done once for all time or it has to check something 24h after some customer action? If the second option that magento cron is enough. Could you tell me example of this customer thing?

Comment: @rafal-kos For example, it has to send an email to a customer 24 hours after that customer buys a product. I don't see how that matters. When an action is done, wait 24 hours and run a script, that's it.

Answer (score 3):

From what you are telling a cron seems just the right tool for this. You say:

> Cron is usually used to run tasks repeatedly rather than once.

Isn't this exactly what you want to do? Maybe if you define like the following it would make more sense. You would want to check every day for a specific condition (customer action) and do a specific task (send email) related to it.

I would say use a cronjob.